# Powershell Script to move different file types with the same name to share folder

Tags: powershell, filenames, move

My source folder contains bunch of *.pdf and *.csv files. I need to move all pairs with the same name to a share folder for further processing. How do I make sure that only existing file pairs will be moved to the share folder?

```
$sourcefolder = "C:\output"
$importfolder = "\\NB-AP-37\Import"

$pdf = Get-ChildItem $sourcefolder | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".pdf"}
$csv = Get-ChildItem $sourcefolder | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".csv"}

foreach ($p in $pdf){
    foreach($c in $csv){
        if($c.BaseName -match $p.BaseName){
        # move both the files to $importfolder
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost there: `Move-Item -Path C:\src.txt -Destination E:\Dir` should do ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-7)):

```
foreach ($p in $pdf){
    foreach($c in $csv){
        if($c.BaseName -eq $p.BaseName){
            # move both the files to $importfolder
            Move-Item -Path $p.FullName -Destination $importfolder
            Move-Item -Path $c.FullName -Destination $importfolder
        }
    }
}
```

And, I changed the comparison to `-eq` because I got some false positives ([operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7)).